# Serving static content with jetty 7, using defaultservlet configured from web.xml

Tags: jetty

This is jetty 7 and xml configured, not embedded.

I'm trying to serve a static file, crossdomain.xml, to an app that connects to a datasource I run from jetty. To do this, I configured a servlet and its mapping thus:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default    </servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>resourceBase    </param-name>
        <param-value>/foo/foo    </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default    </servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*    </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Sadly all I get are 404's. Any help would be much appreciated, btw the rest of my web.xm lfile looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"version="2.5">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cometd    </servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cometd.server.continuation.ContinuationCometdServlet    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1    </load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cometd    </servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*    </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default    </servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>resourceBase    </param-name>
        <param-value>/foo/foo    </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default    </servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*    </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>initializer    </servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foo.research.Initializer    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2    </load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin    </filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin    </filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*    </url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue; here is a snippet that works (Jetty 6.1.22).
I basically replaced org.eclipse with org.mortbay and removed the 
resourceBase parameter (but see below). And this actually ends up in my web.xml file inside my WAR file:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>foo.bar.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <display-name></display-name>
    <description>The smallest Servlet ever!</description>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Then, you have to put your static files in the "static" directory in your
WAR file. Like this (just to make it clear):

```
  ROOT.war
  |_ WEB-INF/
  |_ static/
```

If you want to put your static files elsewhere (but still map them under
the /static/ URI), you can use the resourceBase parameter to specify the
directory, just like you did.

Jetty's documentation helped me to understand this a little bit better:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Servlets+Bundled+with+Jetty

Comment: For Jetty 7 and 8, use org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet instead of org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet